# function exists but fire bug says not defined

Tags: jquery

I have a div on click , and function very well exisits in the file. I verified through firebug also , but still it says.

**showPopUP is not defined**

It was all working good , suddenly it stopped working.

any clues how to debug this issue. We did a file aggregation and all tha javascripts at the runtime are aggregated in one file. But this was all working good till yesterday.

The div click is jquery kind of click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not lying.  Check spelling (remembering that js is case sensitive) and check that the function declaration is in scope.  If you can post a link to a demo page I'm sure we could quickly identify your problem.

Comment: Hi Ken , its all production code it was all working good till today. Nobody changed that javascript file. All we did is we regenerated the aggregated file again. I don't know how i can show you the problem , our QA environments are notexposed outside and in production its working good. I will find a way and get back to you. Is there could be anyother problem apart from spelling mistake.

Comment: @gov - If the `showPopUP()` function can still be found in the aggregated code, the other shot is that it's being called prior to being set (which would fall under Ken's proviso "check that the function declaration is in scope")

Comment: @gov: Are you sure that there are no other javascript errors reported? Aggregating files can sometimes create syntax problems(ex: missing ;). If this is the case the javascript execution may crash before it reaches the lines that initialize your function.... Or as danlefree said you might aggregate the files in the wrong order

Comment: Thank you all , there is some problem with the aggregation only

Comment: THanks for pointing in right direction, once again...thanks to stackoverflow.